# Azure app service private container registry login problem

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-functions

I am using gitlab container registry and azure app service. in the app service I pull container from gitlab and serve it as a service. My problem is I push the new image from gitlab-ci.yaml to app's container settings but the problem is it clears up the login and password info under container settings, each time I push a new container version. So, I have to type my gitlab deploy token in the container settings page. How can I prevent this? Thanks.  See the image

[image]

Comment: How do you "push the new image from gitlab-ci.yaml to app's container settings" ?

Comment: az webapp create --resource-group webapps --plan myplan-8fa7 --name myWebApp 
--deployment-container-image-name "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/myWebApp:$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG-$CI_PIPELINE_IID" --docker-registry-server-user "$REGISTRY_USERNAME" --docker-registry-server-password "$REGISTRY_PASSWORD"

Comment: Ok, that's for the App Service creation but how do you update it? "each time I push a new container version"

Comment: The same process repeats. A new image gets build via my docker-build stage and then the step above runs again with the created new image. Basically reruns the az webapp create line when there is a new build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here agree with **CSharpRocks**, according to the official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-custom-container?pivots=container-linux#deploy-the-image-and-test-the-app), we need to use the [az webapp config container set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/config/container?view=azure-cli-latest&preserve-view=true#az-webapp-config-container-set) command to specify the container registry and the image to deploy for the web app:

```
az webapp config container set --name <app-name> --resource-group AppSvc-DockerTutorial-rg --docker-custom-image-name <registry-name>.azurecr.io/appsvc-tutorial-custom-image:latest --docker-registry-server-url https://<registry-name>.azurecr.io
```

For details:

Replace `<app_name>` with the name of your web app and replace `<registry-name>` in two places with the name of your registry.

- When using a registry other than Docker Hub (as this example shows),
  `--docker-registry-server-url` must be formatted as `https://` followed by the fully qualified domain name of the registry.
- The message, "No credential was provided to access Azure Container
  Registry. Trying to look up..." tells you that Azure is using the
  app's managed identity to authenticate with the container registry
  rather than asking for a username and password.
- If you encounter the error, "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'reserved'", make sure your `<app-name>` is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using this to update your Web App

```
az webapp create
```

Try using

```
az webapp config container set --docker-custom-image-name MyDockerCustomImage --docker-registry-server-password StrongPassword --docker-registry-server-url [] --docker-registry-server-user DockerUserId --name MyWebApp --resource-group MyResourceGroup
```

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/config/container?view=azure-cli-latest#az_webapp_config_container_set)